# Django -- Error table doesn't exist, but it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, django

I had a many-to-many relationship in my models, which was working perfectly fine for the forms, etc...
I realized it made more sense having it in another way, so I've removed the old table and updated the field name and pointed it to the new table as a manytomanyfield.
I removed all the references in all files within the project to the old table.
Removed all .pyc files so they were created again.
(greped all the structure looking for any reference and none was left)

And the forms still try to use the old table, as I removed it from the DB, it keeps failing.

It's basically trying to use a table that it shouldn't use.

What could I be missing? Anyway to get the forms to stop using the old table?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: You should look into [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for your Django projects. It is built to help you with model refactoring like this, to prevent these kinds of things. I really, really, really recommend using it with Django.

Comment: Thanks, going to get it installed and use it. Will it be able to fix the problem, or just avoid it happening again in the future?

Comment: So you removed the table, updated the models.py then ran `python manage.py sql your_app`..?

Comment: I removed the table, udpated the models, ran python manage.py syncdb and used django-evolution afterwards (using it for when syncdb doesn't do the changes).
When I run " python manage.py sql input" it keeps showing the old table there. No idea where it gets it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being a dumbass, it turns out that Django automatically creates a new table to manage the many to many relations.
But it used the same name as my old table, that's why I was getting confused.
Recreated the table using the output from manage.py sql and it's working perfectly